Ubuntu 24.10 load partial swapfile when resuming from hibernation
I set up hibernation with a swapfile that matches the size of my RAM.
When resuming operation the entire swapfile is loaded which takes a significant amount of time.
The actually used memory is only about 1GB most of the time, so I would like Ubuntu to only load the used part of the swapfile, which to me seems like a good standard behavior.
Is there a way to achieve this without having to change the kernel?
